# Macro to copy and paste cell to offset lookup

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, lookup

I can't seem to find the right code for what I want to do. I've designed a very basic POS type system in excel for our shop:

[image: Sale]

When a stock number is typed into column A, column B,C,D & E are populated using Index & Match formula.

When I press the cash/card/cheque button, Excel copies the information and pastes it in another sheet, then resets the form.

This all works perfectly. However, what I also want to happen when the buttons are pressed is for Excel to copy the date and time at the top , search for the stock numbers in column A in the "Stock" sheet, and paste it into column I (Date Sold) of all the relevant cells.

I have no idea how to even start this. Below is the current code for the button. It's not pretty, but it does the job:

```
Sub CASH()
Range("F19").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "CASH"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sale")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sales")

copySheet.Range("A1:F20").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(3, 0).PasteSpecial 
Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-19, 0).PasteSpecial 
Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.Goto Reference:="Default"
Selection.Copy
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A2").Select
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!